# Searching for calls to a function with a certain number of arguments / where the N-th argument matches a regex

Tags: regex, shell, unix

I am looking for any unix command line tools (to be used on Linux and Mac OS X with GNU tools installed) which allows me to search through the source code of a large C++ (or Java, or ...) project and does one or both of the following:

Given the name of a function and a positive integer N,

- find all calls to that function where the N-th parameter is equal to a certain value resp. matches a certain regex
- find all calls to that function where the number of arguments to the function is exactly N (alternatively: at least / at most / less than / greater than).

Of course in full generallity, this may be arbitrarily hard, but I am assuming here that the code base is sufficiently nice, so parameters to those function calls are just strings, numbers, other function calls, arithmetic expressions, etc., but not, say, lambda expressions or some other crazy stuff. I also do not mind the occassional false positive, and I don't worry about class names / templates etc. being confused with the function name.

Indeed, if one worries about false positives / negatives, a variation would be to list all occurance of the function name, and then for each list the number of arguments, or `unknown` if the script failed to determine it.

I am pretty sure I could write a perl script to do most of what I need, but this seems like such a useful tool that I am wondering (hoping? :) whether somebody already wrote something something like this -- perhaps even based on, say, clang, and using the AST for each source file. Though soemthing based on plain text parsing might be better in that it would probably be easy to adapt it to other languages.

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if it can do all of this (but it might do some of it or be a place to start) but `cscope` might be of some use here.

Comment: I would try RegEx - because it is just an awesome tool - starting with 'grep 'function'` and extending it from there.

Comment: Regular languages (and hence regex) cannot match arbitrarily nested pairs of parens, brackets, quotes, etc. -- though of course there are some extensions to "regex" which are not "regular" anymore, and which allow dealing with this (e.g. some add a "recursion" feature).... Anyway, yes, as I said, I could certainly roll my own -- my question was precisely to find out whether somebody already did the work, before spending effort on it myself :)